# Why is npm install gulp adding 318 packages if it's a fresh install?

Tags: npm, gulp, dependencies

I'm installing gulp on a new machine after 2 years of not having gone through the process and for some reason running `npm install gulp --save-dev` is installing 318 dependencies. Am I doing something wrong? I couldn't find any info on the gulp site that mentions this change on v.4.0.2 so I'm really scratching my head here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you use npm install even to upgrade or to retrieve stored files inside a machine npm silently installs the updated dependencies without taking any permission from the user. It might be possible that npm may have installed a testing or beta version dependencies too, guess you have to take a look in appdata if you are using windows.

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything wrong. It genuinely does have that many dependencies:

[image: Gulp dependency graph]

Generated by [npm.broofa.com](http://npm.broofa.com/?q=gulp)

As an aside, it's interesting to compare how much this has changed over time: [@3.9.1](http://npm.broofa.com/?q=gulp@3.9.1), [@3.0.0](http://npm.broofa.com/?q=gulp@3.0.0), [@1.2.1](http://npm.broofa.com/?q=gulp@1.2.1)